# ¿Qué función tiene el «sus» en «Ya tiene sus años»?

Tags: gramática, posesivos

Hoy vi en una pregunta de la página hermana de SE para alemán una cita que puede traducirse así:

> "¡Cuando pienso qué dificultades me dio el idoma inglés! Pero esto ya tiene sus treinta años."

Quizá la combinación siguiente sería más propia del español:

> Ya tiene sus años.

Si escucho *ya tiene algunos años* siento que es un evento más reciente que alguno que *ya tenga sus años*.

¿Qué función tiene el *sus*? ¿Qué tipo de palabra es?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo indica la RAE en la tercera acepción de ["su"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YUFeT07):

> 3. adj. poses. 3.ª pers. coloq. Antepuesto a un nombre propio, aporta valor afectivo o enfático. *Siempre está hablando de su Luis*.

Es decir, cuando se dice *ya tiene sus años*, el adjetivo *sus* enfatiza *años* dando la connotación de que *ya tiene muchos años*.

Otro ejemplo:

> Bojan prometía mucho como futbolista de jovencito. Ahora que ya tiene
>   **sus** años, vemos que tampoco llegó a tanto.

Comment: this makes it look like, additionally, "sus años" is a phrase for "having reached adulthood" or having matriculated in some fashion

Comment: Y se puede usar con otras personas además de la tercera. *Yo ya tengo mis problemas*, por ejemplo.

Comment: "Antepuesto a un nombre propio" ... no es exactamente esa acepción

Answer (score 6):

Es una construcción *sui generis*, coloquial, con sentido enfático y ponderativo. Es cercana (aunque no idéntica, en mi opinión) a la acepción de "su" que menciona la respuesta de fedorqui. Hay también una relación, creo que más estrecha, con la construcción **"lo suyo"**; del [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YqlzSAz):

> loc. pronom. coloq. Pondera la dificultad, mérito o importancia de algo. *Traducir a Horacio tiene lo suyo.*

Answer (score 3):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/su) tiene una entrada bastante clara:

(uso enfático)

⇒ tendrá sus buenos 80 años | he must be a good 80 years old

⇒ su dinero le habrá costado | it must have cost her a pretty penny

⇒ una casa de muñecas con sus cortinitas y todo | a doll's house with little curtains and everything